# setTimeout and setInterval

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I want to make this counter starts working within 5 seconds of being on the page, but I can not link the setTimeout with setInterval , you would know how could I?

[image]

Comment: better to copy paste the code rather than code  image

Comment: and who cares a photo that code ... and put me up negative

Comment: First off all i can say  did not downvote for this question .If somebody downvotes it then it sounds like  you need to improve your question standard.

Comment: @PedroVB It is much easier to answer if we can copy your source code instead of typing it character by character.

Comment: tell me your ultimate goal . with all conditions

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your interval with the setTimeout function:

```
// interval variable 
var cycle = 10;
// variable for the interval since we are invoking it within a function, the callMeEverySecond function can't reach it
var t;
var callMeEverySecond = function() {
    cycle--;
    // Logs the Date to the console
    console.log(new Date());
    if(cycle === 0) {
        console.log("stop this");
        clearInterval(t);
        // do something further.
    }
}

// Start the timeout after 5 seconds
setTimeout(function() {
    // call the function 'callMeEverySecond' each second
    t = setInterval(callMeEverySecond, 1000);
}, 5000);
```

http://devdocs.io/dom/window.settimeout
And a small tutorial: http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval

Comment: if it works, but what happens now is that when it reaches 0 starts counting with negative numbers ..... and does not appear so to continue

Comment: Whats you goal? Should the counter restart after being 0 ? Just set the "tiempoInicial" to 10 again!

Comment: that when the counter reaches 0 appear  " Continue"  and give me click to another page

Comment: Okay, I've edited my answer. The function stops after the interval and you can set your div.

Answer (score 0):

Is this ok

```
var tiempoInicial = 10;
function tiempo() {
    document.getElementById('contador').innerHTML='Puedes continuar en ' + tiempoInicial + ' segundos.';
    if(tiempoInicial==0) {
        clearInterval(t);
        document.getElementById("contador").innerHTML = "<p id=\"forumulario\" onclick=\"goToForm1()\">Continuar</p>";
    }
}
function iniciar() {
    var t = setInterval(tiempo,1000);
    clearTimeout(ini);
}
var ini = setTimeout(iniciar, 5000);
```

Sorry, I tried out the code above and it didn't work so I changed it a bit.

This is the new code.

```
var tiempoInicial = 10;
function tiempo() {
    document.getElementById('contador').innerHTML='Puedes continuar en ' + tiempoInicial + ' segundos.';
    tiempoInicial--;
    if(tiempoInicial < -1) {
        clearInterval(t);
        document.getElementById("contador").innerHTML = "<p id=\"forumulario\" onclick=\'goToForm1()\'>Continuar</p>";
    }
}
function iniciar() {
    t = setInterval(tiempo,1000);
    clearTimeout(ini);
}
var ini = setTimeout(iniciar, 5000);
```